# Tkinter widget picking up wrong font

Tags: python, tkinter

I have several buttons and labels in my gui. In my list of buttons, the last button seems to pick up the font of the next label. What am I missing?

I put the font I want for the button directly in the class that creates the button. But somehow, the last one uses the font settings for the next frame.

```
from tkFont import Font

class ChannelDisplay(Frame):
    """ Making a custom canvas to hold
        the status bubble
        the (sub)component name (button to launch subcomponent tree)
        the toggle 'X' ChkButtonCanvas"""

    def __init__(self, master=None, label='NONE', status='NONE',**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        button_font = Font(family='Helvetica',size=12) #<<<This is the font style I expect to be applied to all the buttons.
        self.lbl = label
        self.status = status
        self.bool = BooleanVar()

        self.component = Button(self, text=self.lbl, font=button_font, command=self.new_win)
        self.component.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.bool.set(TRUE)
        self.toggle = Checkbutton(self, variable=self.bool)
        self.toggle.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.bubble = Canvas(self,width=32,height=32)
        self.bubble.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.circle(self.bubble,x=17, y=17, r=14, status='--')

    def circle(self,canvas, x, y, r, status='grey'):
        if status == 'BAD':
            id = canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill='red')
        elif status == 'GOOD':
            id = canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill='green')
        else:
            id = canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill='grey')
        return id

    def new_win(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self)
        self.newWindow.wm_title(self.lbl)
        newLabel = Label(Toplevel,text=self.lbl)
        newLabel.grid()

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.List = ['A&G','CRCS']

        self.timeData = StringVar()
        self.timeData.set('same font as "CRCS" button?')
        self.versionData = StringVar()
        self.versionData.set('A not good version')
        self.modeData = StringVar()
        self.modeData.set('Day Mode')

        for item in self.List:
            self.chanButton = ChannelDisplay(top_frame,label=item,status='GOOD')
            self.chanButton.grid()
        self.createBottomFrame()

    def createBottomFrame(self):

        self.timefont = Font(family='Times', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.time = Label(btm_frame, textvariable=self.timeData, font=self.timefont)
        self.time.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, ipady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.versionfont = Font(family='Times', size=24)
        self.version = Label(btm_frame, textvariable=self.versionData, font=self.versionfont)
        self.version.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=4, pady=10, sticky="e")

        self.modefont = Font(family='Times', size=32, weight='bold')
        self.mode = Label(btm_frame, textvariable=self.modeData, font=self.modefont)
        self.mode.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=1, pady=10, sticky="w")


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Telescope Health Status")
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


top_frame = Frame(root, bg='light blue', padx=30)
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20, sticky='ew')
btm_frame = Frame(root, bg='pink')
btm_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I want the button that says 'CRCS' to be the same as the button that says 'A&G'. But it is the same as the self.time label.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use `Font`? What about passing it as a parameter directly, i.e. `self.component = Button(self, text=self.lbl, font="Helvetica 12", command=self.new_win)`?

Comment: I thought it was easier to be able to re-use the font set up in different elements. In the ChannelDiscplay class, I use it for a label and a button. (I didn't include the condition when I use labels, to keep it minimal.)